# Customizing Keyframe Naming using Katna Package in Python to Reflect Video Frame Times

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, video-editing

I am using the [Katna](https://katna.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Python package to extract keyframes from a video. The package works well for my needs, but I am trying to customize the naming convention for the extracted keyframes. Specifically, I want the name of each keyframe to be associated with the time of the corresponding frame in the video.

I attempted to modify the source code of Katna to implement this feature, but I encountered difficulties in the process. Is there a solution available to integrate this functionality within the Katna package, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this goal?

I also experimented with OpenCV to extract the time of each frame, but the process was time-consuming and inefficient for my requirements.

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
from Katna.video import Video
from Katna.video import Video
from Katna.writer import KeyFrameDiskWriter
import os

# For windows, the below if condition is must.
if __name__ == "__main__":

  # initialize video module
  vd = Video()

  # number of images to be returned
  no_of_frames_to_returned = 96
  

  # initialize diskwriter to save data at desired location
  diskwriter = KeyFrameDiskWriter(location="selectedframes")

  # Video file path
  video_file_path = os.path.join("/home/plumpi/Desktop/test_katna", "exp.mp4")

  print(f"Input video file path = {video_file_path}")

  # extract keyframes and process data with diskwriter
  vd.extract_video_keyframes(
       no_of_frames=no_of_frames_to_returned, file_path=video_file_path,
       writer=diskwriter
  )
```

source code of katna for extracting keyframes:

```
"""
```

.. module:: Katna.frame_extractor
:platform: OS X
:synopsis: This module has functions related to key frame extraction
"""

import cv2
import operator
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

import tempfile
import Katna.config as config

class FrameExtractor(object):
"""Class for extraction of key frames from video : based on sum of absolute differences in LUV colorspace from given video
"""

```
def __init__(self):

    # Setting local maxima criteria
    self.USE_LOCAL_MAXIMA = config.FrameExtractor.USE_LOCAL_MAXIMA
    # Lenght of sliding window taking difference
    self.len_window = config.FrameExtractor.len_window
    # Chunk size of Images to be processed at a time in memory
    self.max_frames_in_chunk = config.FrameExtractor.max_frames_in_chunk

def __calculate_frame_difference(self, curr_frame, prev_frame):
    """Function to calculate the difference between current frame and previous frame

    :param frame: frame from the video
    :type frame: numpy array
    :param curr_frame: current frame from the video in LUV format
    :type curr_frame: numpy array
    :param prev_frame: previous frame from the video in LUV format
    :type prev_frame: numpy array
    :return: difference count and frame if None is empty or undefined else None
    :rtype: tuple
    """

    if curr_frame is not None and prev_frame is not None:
        # Calculating difference between current and previous frame
        diff = cv2.absdiff(curr_frame, prev_frame)
        count = np.sum(diff)
        return count
    return None

def __process_frame(self, frame, prev_frame, frame_diffs, frames):
    """Function to calculate the difference between current frame and previous frame

    :param frame: frame from the video
    :type frame: numpy array
    :param prev_frame: previous frame from the video in LUV format
    :type prev_frame: numpy array
    :param frame_diffs: list of frame differences
    :type frame_diffs: list of int
    :param frames: list of frames
    :type frames: list of numpy array
    :return: previous frame and current frame
    :rtype: tuple
    """

    luv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)
    curr_frame = luv
    # Calculating the frame difference for previous and current frame
    frame_diff = self.__calculate_frame_difference(curr_frame, prev_frame)
    
    if frame_diff is not None:
        #count, frame = frame_diff
        frame_diffs.append(frame_diff)
        frames.append(frame)
    del prev_frame
    prev_frame = curr_frame
    
    return prev_frame, curr_frame

def __extract_all_frames_from_video__(self, videopath):
    """Generator function for extracting frames from a input video which are sufficiently different from each other, 
    and return result back as list of opencv images in memory

    :param videopath: inputvideo path
    :type videopath: `str`
    :return: Generator with extracted frames in max_process_frames chunks and difference between frames
    :rtype: generator object with content of type [numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray] 
    """
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(str(videopath))

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    i = 1
    chunk_no = 0
    
    while ret:
        curr_frame = None
        prev_frame = None

        frame_diffs = []
        frames = []
        for _ in range(0, self.max_frames_in_chunk):
            if ret:
                # Calling process frame function to calculate the frame difference and adding the difference 
                # in **frame_diffs** list and frame to **frames** list
                prev_frame, curr_frame = self.__process_frame(frame, prev_frame, frame_diffs, frames)
                i = i + 1
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                # print(frame_count)
            else:
                cap.release()
                break
        chunk_no = chunk_no + 1
        yield frames, frame_diffs
    cap.release()

def __get_frames_in_local_maxima__(self, frames, frame_diffs):
    """ Internal function for getting local maxima of key frames 
    This functions Returns one single image with strongest change from its vicinity of frames 
    ( vicinity defined using window length ) 

    :param object: base class inheritance
    :type object: class:`Object`
    :param frames: list of frames to do local maxima on
    :type frames: `list of images`
    :param frame_diffs: list of frame difference values 
    :type frame_diffs: `list of images`

    """
    extracted_key_frames = []
    diff_array = np.array(frame_diffs)
    # Normalizing the frame differences based on windows parameters
    sm_diff_array = self.__smooth__(diff_array, self.len_window)

    # Get the indexes of those frames which have maximum differences
    frame_indexes = np.asarray(argrelextrema(sm_diff_array, np.greater))[0]

    for frame_index in frame_indexes:
        extracted_key_frames.append(frames[frame_index - 1])
    del frames[:]
    del sm_diff_array
    del diff_array
    del frame_diffs[:]
    return extracted_key_frames

def __smooth__(self, x, window_len, window=config.FrameExtractor.window_type):
    """smooth the data using a window with requested size.
    This method is based on the convolution of a scaled window with the signal.
    The signal is prepared by introducing reflected copies of the signal
    (with the window size) in both ends so that transient parts are minimized
    in the begining and end part of the output signal.
    example:
    import numpy as np
    t = np.linspace(-2,2,0.1)
    x = np.sin(t)+np.random.randn(len(t))*0.1
    y = smooth(x)
    see also:
    numpy.hanning, numpy.hamming, numpy.bartlett, numpy.blackman, numpy.convolve
    scipy.signal.lfilter
    
    :param x: the frame difference list
    :type x: numpy.ndarray
    :param window_len: the dimension of the smoothing window
    :type window_len: slidding window length
    :param window: the type of window from 'flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman' flat window will produce a moving average smoothing.
    :type window: str
    :return: the smoothed signal
    :rtype: ndarray
    """
    # This function takes 
    if x.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError("smooth only accepts 1 dimension arrays.")

    #if x.size < window_len:
    #    raise ValueError("Input vector needs to be bigger than window size.")

    if x.size < window_len:
        return x

    if not window in ["flat", "hanning", "hamming", "bartlett", "blackman"]:
        raise ValueError("Smoothing Window is on of 'flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman'")

    # Doing row-wise merging of frame differences wrt window length. frame difference
    # by factor of two and subtracting the frame differences from index == window length in reverse direction
    s = np.r_[2 * x[0] - x[window_len:1:-1], x, 2 * x[-1] - x[-1:-window_len:-1]]

    if window == "flat":  # moving average
        w = np.ones(window_len, "d")
    else:
        w = getattr(np, window)(window_len)
    y = np.convolve(w / w.sum(), s, mode="same")
    return y[window_len - 1 : -window_len + 1]

def extract_candidate_frames(self, videopath):
    """ Pubic function for this module , Given and input video path
    This functions Returns one list of all candidate key-frames  

    :param object: base class inheritance
    :type object: class:`Object`
    :param videopath: inputvideo path
    :type videopath: `str`
    :return: opencv.Image.Image objects
    :rtype: list
    """

    extracted_candidate_key_frames = []

    # Get all frames from video in chunks using python Generators
    frame_extractor_from_video_generator = self.__extract_all_frames_from_video__(
        videopath
    )

    # Loop over every frame in the frame extractor generator object and calculate the
    # local maxima of frames 
    for frames, frame_diffs in frame_extractor_from_video_generator:
        extracted_candidate_key_frames_chunk = []
        if self.USE_LOCAL_MAXIMA:

            # Getting the frame with maximum frame difference
            extracted_candidate_key_frames_chunk = self.__get_frames_in_local_maxima__(
                frames, frame_diffs
            )
            extracted_candidate_key_frames.extend(
                extracted_candidate_key_frames_chunk
            )

    return extracted_candidate_key_frames
```

What I tried:

I attempted to modify the source code of the Katna package to customize the naming convention of the extracted keyframes. Specifically, I aimed to integrate a feature that associates the name of each keyframe with the precise time of the corresponding frame in the video.

My expectation:

I expected that by modifying the source code, I would be able to incorporate the functionality to automatically assign the time of each frame to the corresponding keyframe's name.

Actual result:

However, despite my efforts to make the necessary changes to the Katna package, I encountered difficulties and was unable to achieve the desired outcome. The modified code did not produce the intended naming convention based on the frame times, and I was unable to identify the source of the issue.

Comment: you forgot to add the code...

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i added the code but the code is similar to katna documentation